# System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. c#

Tags: c#, math, addition

Sorry if its duplicate. I didn't even know what to write as a title.

**Introduction:**

I was trying to make the adder as a console application.

**Problem:**

When I run the program, everything works until the 24th line. It will show an error. (img. 1)

**What I tried:**

nothing. When I look at the code, I don't see any error there.

Thank you

Code:

```
void write(string towrite)
{
    Console.WriteLine(towrite);
}

//Lets make calculator
string inputoutput;
int num1;
int num2;
write("CALCULATOR");
write("__________");
write("");
write("Write addition problem:");
scitani:
inputoutput = Console.ReadLine();
num1 = Convert.ToInt32(inputoutput.Substring(0, inputoutput.IndexOf('+')));
num2 = Convert.ToInt32(inputoutput.Substring(num1.ToString().Length + 1, 0));
inputoutput = Convert.ToString(num1 + num2);
Console.Clear();
write("CALCULATOR");
write("__________");
write(inputoutput);
goto scitani;
```

I'm sorry, but I'm Czech and I have VS in Czech. As you can see in img. 1.

[img. 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afiCF.png)

Comment: Instead of `Convert.ToInt32` use `int.Parse`, if you handle user input always `int.TryParse`.

Comment: The second parameter for substring is the length you take https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-6.0#system-string-substring(system-int32-system-int32) you likely don't want to specify it, just use the single parameter overload https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-6.0#system-string-substring(system-int32)

Comment: Also don't use goto unless there's no other convenient choice. do while is a better choice https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements#the-do-statement

Comment: As an aside, I'd also a) learn and follow .NET naming conventions; b) declare variables at the point of initialization, rather than all at the top of the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `Substring` without a second parameter, then you take the remaining part until end, otherwise you take the part with the specified length.

You should also use `int.TryParse` if you handle user input. Here is a sample:

```
void Main()
{
    int? result = CalcPlus("10 + 17");
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

static int? CalcPlus(string input)
{
    int plusIndex = input.IndexOf('+');
    if(plusIndex == -1)
    {
        return null;
    }
    
    string first = input.Remove(plusIndex).Trim(); // same as Substring(0, plusIndex).Trim()
    string last = input.Substring(plusIndex + 1).Trim();
    
    if(!int.TryParse(first, out int firstInt))
    {
        return null;
    }
    
    if(!int.TryParse(last, out int lastInt))
    {
        return null;
    }
    
    return firstInt + lastInt;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew I can trim string, but I forgot how to do that. :) ( I still don't see any problem in my old code. :(  )

Comment: I just remembered! I was using string.Remove()!

Comment: @slavekrouta: this is the problem: `Substring(num1.ToString().Length + 1, 0)` Your second parameter to [Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-6.0#system-string-substring(system-int32-system-int32)) is 0, but thats the length.

Comment: OK. I just realised that.